# Parsing the # segment from an incoming URI in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a few lines of javascript that parse out an access token from a redirect URI that Dropbox sends me after my user has successfully logged in to Dropbox and requested access to my Dropbox App.  Once I get the access token loaded into a variable, I then send the variable as an input parameter in a FileMaker script I have that then stores the token into the users preferences.

1. Take an incoming (Redirect) URL from Dropbox containing a token for my user.  The token is the first string after the #.  Here’s an example of what Dropbox sends me:

   `https://myServer/dropbox.html#access_token=sl.BpYUz-Ey3Sxh3futS_EbAOhJcX_opQ4NB8nbjAawJcoH99q1L8952LaEps0rGt_W_ARy0ZDD38LiBckTdqi3RATbT8evA57ysqvQO8o1V4z76MjiVA2VzBMbMi_84JiFxXA4tie0&token_type=bearer&expires_in=14400&scope=account_info.read+files.content.write+files.metadata.read+files.metadata.write&uid=60558915&account_id=dbid%3AAADgKd0bJIMHUI_EmJFGWw9UTPV_CEkLlhg&state=NameOfmyFile`
2. The long string between `#access_token=` and `&token_type` is what I need.
3. Here’s where I am at, learning-wise, please correct!

   // I declare a variable:
   Const IncomingURL  = window.location.href
   // this loads the incoming URI into my variable, IncomingURL
   // I parse the token out of the variable:
   Const TheToken = (parsefunction (IncomingURL))

I then send my variable as an input parameter to my FileMaker app using the fmp: uri.

Can anyone help with the “parse function” that I’m looking for?  And please remember that I am a rank amateur ;>) Thanks!

I am working with Visual Studio Code as well as the Live Server extension to view it.  I just need this tiny little file to store on my server to grab this.

Comment: I would split the url string at the "#", then split based on "&", then finally by "=" with key-value pairs. The `#` seems a little odd to me, because if it was `?`, then you could use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: A simple way to do this, which isn't on the duplicate answer, is to use `indexOf` and `substring`. Here's an example. Sorry comments don't do a good job of supporting code.

    const str = 'testblahblah#access_token=Bob_Rodes_loves_to_see_his_name_in_print&token_typeblahblahmoreblabbertyblah';
    const startString = '#access_token=';
    const start = str.indexOf(startString) + startString.length;
    const end = str.indexOf('&token_type');

    console.log(str.substring(start, end)); // Bob_Rodes_loves_to_see_his_name_in_print